# How to switch active class with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4

Please, hear me out. I'm still new to html and jquery, and I know this question has been asked a number of times, but I don't know why the solutions don't work for my problem.

I want to be able to switch the active class in my navbar when I click another link. What am I missing? :(

This is the html

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light p-1">
  <a class="navbar-brand m-0" href=" /"><img src="" width="281" height="31.6"></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler border-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse text-dark" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav m-auto text-center">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/blog">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/contact">Contact</a>
      </li>

      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="/login">Login/Register</a>
      </li>

    </ul>
    <form class="form-inline m-2 my-lg-0" action="/search/">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I have tried so many solutions including

```
<script>
  $('document').on('click', function(){
    $('.navbar .navbar-nav').find('li.active').removeClass( 'active' );
    $(this).addClass( 'active' );
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You should attach the click event on .nav-items not the whole document

Comment: '$('document').on('click', function(){' get the click anywhere on your page, in other words on any element of the page , even on the form, or on his button

Comment: @EriksKlotins I've tried it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @MisterJojo thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Have you resolved this?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/

Comment: @EGC no I haven't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('div#navbarSupportedContent li.nav-item').on('click', function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().find('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. With this, the active class switches, but the actual pages don't open up. You've just unlocked another level of confusion unlocked. lol

Comment: Yes. `ev.preventDefault()` do it. if you leave the side you lose everything. One solution would be to set the class active server side? For example with php or python?

Comment: How is your website structured? Do you have several static pages?

Comment: Yes it does. It's a django webapp, and this is a 'nav.html' file included in a base.html file. Sorry for the late reply, i've got so much going on right now.

Comment: Hi, I took out the `ev.preventDefault();` line, and the active class switches, but it returns to the 'Home' link when the page opens. So I just removed the `active` class from the 'Home' link. It's not how I want it to work, but it's better than not switching at all. Thanks a lot.